# How to write text after a circle with a number in it

Tags: html, css

So,I'm struggling to solve a strange thing that happens in my html code.

I've been trying to do this for 3 days or maybe more but I simply cannot find out the 'problem'.

```css
.variola {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.199219) 0px 0px 20px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  "

}
</style> <style> .cerculet {
  display: block;
  font-size: 120%;
  line-height: 145%;
  width: 1.6em;
  height: 1.6em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style> <style> .introducere {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align length: 5;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Aici va fi scris orice cod CSS pentru ca ulterior sa fie "preluat" intr-un
mod indirect de catre codul HTML pentru imbogatirea paginii web. -->

  <title>10 cele mai periculoase boli care au facut istorie</title>
</head>

<body>
  10 cele mai periculoase boli care au facut istorie
  <!-- Tot codul de la tag-ul "body" deschis pana la "body" inchis este strict
codul pentru pagina web.Cei in head sub tag-ul "style" este cod in CSS si 
nu va aparea in pagina web,ci va "imbogati" intr-un mod indirect codul html -->

  <p style="text-align: left">
    <img align="absmiddle" src="http://s2.postimg.org/6zkw8piph/Time.png">26-Martie-2015 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <!-- "&nbsp" este un cod important folosit pentru a crea un blank(spatiu alb)
intre 2 caractere -->
    <img align="absmiddle" src="http://s29.postimg.org/tkzbm9nwz/Domeniu.png">Biologie
    <br>
    <img align="absmiddle" src="http://s22.postimg.org/k7tec39x9/Tags.png">Tags: Pandemii, cele mai periculoase</p>
  <hr noshade size="2" style="text-align: left" width="47%">
  <br>
  <!-- Cu ajutorul tag-ului "hr" se pot introduce linii in pagina web.

"noshade" inseamna ca linia nu o sa aiba contur. -->

  <h2></h2>

  <div class="cerculet">
    <div>
      <h2>1 </h2>

      <div>
        <h2>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <big style="font-weight: bold">A ucis mai mult de 300 de
                milioane de oameni<br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                din intreaga lume in secolul al XX-lea si pe cei<br>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                mai multi locuitori nativi ai Americii.</big> 
                <!-- Exact ceea ce spuneam mai sus:codul CSS va fi "preluat" indirect din "head"
si va fi introdus in codul html,combinand cele 2 limbaje. -->
                 <!-- :-) --></h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div>
    Variola(cunoscuta si sub numele latin "Variola" sau "Variola vera") este o boala contagioasa
    <br>unica oamenilor.Variola este cauza fie de virusul numit Variola Major,fie de cel numit Variola
    <br>minor.Forma mai letala,V. Major,are o mortalitate de 30-35%,pe cand V. Minor este o forma
    <br>mai usoara a bolii numita alastrim si ucide ~1% din victimele sale.Efectele secundare
    <br>de termen lung pentru supravietuitori includ cicatrici pe piele.Alte efecte secundare ocazionale
    <br>includ orbire datorita ulcerului de cornee si infertilitate la persoanele de sex masculin.
  </div>
  <!-- Tag-ul "br" sectioneaza textul nostru din pagina web in paragrafe. -->
  <br>
  <br>

  <div>
    <b>Variola a ucis aproximativ 60 de milioane de europeni,</b> incluzand cinci monarhi
    <br>care conduceau Europa in secolul al XVIII-lea.Pana la 30% din cei infectati,80% fiind copii sub 5
    <br>ani,au murit datorita acestei boli si inca o treime din supravietuitori au devenit orbi.
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div>
    Cat despre tarile din America,dupa primul contact cu europenii si africanii,unii au crezut ca rata
    <br>de mortalitate de 90-95% a populatiei native din Lumea Noua a fost cauza de boala Lumii Vechi.
    <br>Se suspecteaza ca variola a fost principalul vinovat si raspunzator pentru uciderea a aproape toti
    <br>locuitorii nativi ai Americii.In Mexic,cand aztecii s-au angajat in rascoala impotriva lui Cortés,
    <br>depasiti numeric,spaniolii au fost fortati sa fuga.In timpul luptei,un soldat spaniol purtator de
    <br>variola a murit.Dupa lupta,aztecii au contractat virusul din cadavrele invadatorilor.Cand Cortés
    <br>s-a intors in capitala,variola a devastat populatia azteca.A ucis o mare parte din armata azteca,
    <br>imparatul si 25% din populatia normala.Ulterior,Cortés a infrant cu usurinta aztecii si a intrat in
    <br>Tenochtitlán unde a aflat ca variola a ucis mai multi azteci decat au ucis tunurile.
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div>
    Variola a fost responsabila pentru aproximativ 300-500 de milioane de decese in secolul al XX-lea.
    <br>Nu mai tarziu de 1967, Organizatia Mondiala a Sanatatii (OMS) a estimat ca 15 milioane de persoane
    <br>au contractat virusul si ca alte doua milioane au murit in acel an.Dupa campanii de vaccinare incheiate
    <br>cu succes in timpul secolelor XIX si XX,OMS-ul a oficializat eradicarea variolei in 1979.Pana in ziua de
    <br>astazi,variola este singura boala infectioasa care a fost complet eradicata din natura.
  </div>
  <img class="variola" src="http://s3.postimg.org/cb0l49sw3/Variola.jpg" style="position:absolute; left:150px;">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div class="cerculet">
    <div style="font-family: Cambria; font-size: 120%">
      2
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Aici am folosit CSS-ul pentru a da un stil imaginii urmat de codul
html specific imaginii "style="position...." pentru a aseza imaginea in pozitia
dorita de mine -->
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, after the number 1(colored in black,in a circle),there's a LOT of space that I don't want.

The alignment is not good too.I used lots of `&nbsp` and `<br>`'s just because I can't find a way to put the text immediately after the number 1. I'm trying to make a "site" for a school project and I am allowed to see other sites to "inspire" myself.You can check http://www.oddee.com/item_90608.aspx

and see what I'm trying to "copy" in some kind of way.

Please help.

Comment: Don't post a link to a zip file.  Instead, post the relevant code in the question itself.  Also change the tag from "circle" to "html".

Comment: Well I think you should be nicer.It's my first thread here and I didn't know how the things were working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you want to `float: left` the number/circle so that the content wraps around it. You also have several unnecessary elements and, like you mentioned, unnecessary `&nbsp;` elements - below, I've cleaned the example down to a bare-bones working example.

```css
.cerculet {
  display: block;
}
.cerculet:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: ' ';
}
.cerculet p{
  font-weight: bold;
}
.cerculet h2{
  font-size: 120%;
  line-height: 145%;
  width: 1.6em;
  height: 1.6em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cerculet">
  <h2>1 </h1>
  <p>A ucis mai mult de 300 de milioane de oameni din intreaga lume in secolul al XX-lea si pe cei mai multi locuitori nativi ai Americii.
  </p>
</div>

<p>Variola(cunoscuta si sub numele latin "Variola" sau "Variola vera") este o boala contagioasa unica oamenilor.Variola este cauza fie de virusul numit Variola Major,fie de cel numit Variola minor.Forma mai letala,V. Major,are o mortalitate de 30-35%,pe cand V. Minor este o forma mai usoara a bolii numita alastrim si ucide ~1% din victimele sale.Efectele secundare de termen lung pentru supravietuitori includ cicatrici pe piele.Alte efecte secundare ocazionale includ orbire datorita ulcerului de cornee si infertilitate la persoanele de sex masculin.
</p>

<p><b>Variola a ucis aproximativ 60 de milioane de europeni,</b> incluzand cinci monarhi care conduceau Europa in secolul al XVIII-lea.Pana la 30% din cei infectati,80% fiind copii sub 5 ani,au murit datorita acestei boli si inca o treime din supravietuitori au devenit orbi.
</p>
```